# How to to select jQuery custom checkbox and perform an action

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am using a jQuery custom Radio and Checkbox from: 
**[HERE](http://www.1stwebmagazine.com/demo/jquery-checkbox-and-radio-button-styling.html)**
I am wanting to do Something like: When Check box is selected Perform an action.
In order to do that I made:

```
if($('.main').find('.checked')){
    $('.move').click( function(){
        alert("Hello World");
    });

}
```

Action Should be if check box is selected or have the class .checked, Clicking on any Button which has .move class will give alert "Hello world". Here .main is the div wrapping everything

But That I have used is not getting correct result. It giving me alert always. Is there any proper way to Select that .checked class and perform my action? Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. [Sorry for not giving js fiddle link or example]

[image]

Comment: take a time to read the api of the library you are using ... http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: Actually on that example Actual check box is not being checked it's moved away with position absolute

Comment: so you guessed that you gotta change the selector from input to span, right?

Comment: <span> is visible when it's live with the use of javascripts or jQuery I guess. I want to select that class .check which is inside of <span>.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/safev/2/edit ... hope it helps ... I did it outside the "library function" but I think you should adapt the `on change` method to your needs, whatever they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the plugin you're using, but from having a brief look, try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.custom-check', function(e){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('checked') ) {
        // Do something
    }
    else {
        // Do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was waiting for this type of solution.